# Sort jQuery DataTable after changing column heading text

Tags: jquery, datatables

When I dynamically change the column text of a jQuery datatable, it is no longer possible to sort the table by clicking on that column heading (though sorting the other columns in the table does remain functional). I need to change the column heading dynamically and I also need to sort the table. How can I do this?

I have tried sorting using a couple of different methods:

Method 1:

```
$($('#myTableID').DataTable().column(9).header()).text('new col title');
```

Method 2:

HTML:

```
<table id="myTableID" class="table datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>col 0</th>
            <th>col 1</th>                        
            <th>col 2</th>
            <th>col 3</th>
            <th>col 4</th>
            <th>col 5</th>
            <th>col 6</th>
            <th>col 7</th>
            <th>col 8</th>
            <th><span id="changeMe">col 9</span></th>
            <th>col 10</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

js:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#changeMe').text('new col title');
});
```

Comment: I used your JS to change the column heading; and also changed it via a button `onclick`, as another test - but column header sorting continued to work as expected. Are you able to provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @andrewjames cheers. [i did a quick check](https://jsfiddle.net/7Ln0py25/) and you are right. i will have to investigate and nail down the exact problem